# Getting 'Nonetype' error when trying to create a new list

Tags: python, list, nonetype

```
def simplify(intlist):
  nums = set(intlist)
  nums = bubblesort(list(nums))
  simplified_list = []
  for num in nums:
    count = intlist.count(num)
    if count == 1:
        simplified_list.append(num)
       
    else:
        simplified_list.append([num] * count)
  return(simplified_list)        
  print(simplified_list)
simplify(intlist)
```

I keep getting the 'Nonetype' object is not iterable when running this code. What am I doing wrong with this code?

Comment: post full traceback that you get and also `bubblesort` function, which probably returns `None` and what exactly is `intlist` (a list?).

Comment: Adding to @buran replacing `bubblesort` with `sorted`, the code does not produce any errors.

Comment: From code snippet you shared I can guess that bubblesort returns `None`. There are 2 possibilities. Either there is an implementation error in bubblesort or the function is intended to mutate  (change the value) of the passed parameter. In the later case you should hold the refrence to the list you are passing to the bubblesort function. for more detailed answer you probably should share the bubblesort function or give more information like which module you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Psychic debugging: `bubblesort` operates on its argument in place and returns `None` implicitly (due to a lack of a `return` or an empty `return` statement). Or it doesn't operate in place, and is just buggy, failing to return or modify the argument.

Either way, that means `nums = bubblesort(list(nums))` sets `nums` to `None`, and `for num in nums:` tries to do `for num in None:`, which clearly makes no sense.

Assuming `bubblesort` isn't buggy, it just expects to operate in place, change the first two lines to:

```
nums = list(set(intlist))  # Convert to list here so list bound to name we can reference later
bubblesort(nums)  # Doesn't assign to nums, as it operates in place
```

and it should work.